# How to use neither ...nor... correctly?

Tags: grammar

I saw a question asking which is the correct sentence. The answer is (B) but I don't understand why the other two are wrong.

> (A) There are either exciting news stories or interesting jokes in this paper.
> (B) There are neither exciting news stories nor interesting jokes in this paper.
> (C)There are neither exciting news nor interesting jokes in this paper.

Please let me know why (A) and (C) are incorrect.

Comment: (A) would be an odd thing to say about a newspaper - that there are _either_ stories _or_ jokes in it, but not both! (C) is wrong because it treats 'news' as a countable noun when it is uncountable in English. We say 'There is news' or 'There are news stories'.

Comment: (A) is grammatical, but as Kate implies is about as convincing as 'My wife's name is either Anne or Barbara'. (C) is ungrammatical, again as Kate says. Though I've seen that 'informations' and argued that 'furnitures' are acceptable countifications (in certain usages) nowadays, 'news' remains non-count, singular agreement (there _is_ news about ...) and can't twin with a plural-verbform-requiring noun. Contrast:  'There is neither good news nor bad news.' _OK_ / 'There are neither cattle nor sheep in the field.' _OK_.